# Regexp for parsing a string

Tags: regex

Hello I have troubles in parsing these strings (num of columns is fixed)

```
 9/01 down/down 0/ 0 0/ 0 0/ 0 0/ 0 0%/ 0%
     9/01 up/ up 33172/100014 65/ 111 -106/ 136 33172/100014 100%/100%
```

The final result should be a matrix like:

```
9/01 | down/down | 0/ 0         | 0/ 0    |  0/ 0      |  0/ 0          |  0%/ 0%
9/01 | up/ up    | 33172/100014 | 65/ 111 |  -106/ 136 |  33172/100014  |  100%/100%
```

Could someone help me in writing a regexp for a single input line?

Riccardo

Edit:
My temp solution: [^/]+/[\s]*[^\s]+

Comment: Please show what you have tried, perhaps, you almost did it.

Comment: Do you need code that does that or are you happy with using a text editor?

Comment: [^/]+/[\s]*[^\s]+
This was my solution...

Comment: @Riccardo79 you should put it into the question then.

Comment: Why downvote @stribizhev?

Comment: I did not downvote. You should add your effort to the question itself. And you should have provided that effort from the beginning. Also, you need to describe the problem you have with your solution, what does not work. See [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @stribizhev actually, it seems to have received two downvotes and 1 upvote

Comment: Infact I added my solution... I was working on it ..

Comment: Why a regular expression? The `split` function provided by almost every programming language will just work.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini what is op supposed to split on? Single space? that will split in the wrong places.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini: it is impossible to use a split function. Please read the question. As you can see, there is not a clear delimiter...

Comment: Actually you could do by using the slash `/` as delimiter.

Comment: Then you should merge each group of 2 cells in one group! "9 "01" --> "9/01". Too bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh this is a lot better. Something @ndn would be proud of, I think. :p

```
([\w\/%\-\s]+?)(?:\b\s|$)
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vR5eD2/3)

If you want everything captured in the line right away into separate capture groups you can use this:

```
(\d+\/\d+)\s+(\w+\/\s?\w+)\s+([\d-]+\/\s?[\d-]+)\s+([\d-]+\/\s?[\d-]+)\s+([\d-]+\/\s?[\d-]+)\s+([\d-]+\/\s?[\d-]+)\s+([\d-%]+\/\s?[\d%]+)
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vR5eD2/4)

Comment: What is the difference with [^/]+/[\s]*[^\s]+

Comment: @Riccardo79 well for one, yours is capturing unnecessary spaces. If you want a longer regular expression that will capture everything in one line for you, i can bring back something from my edits.

Comment: @Riccardo79 see the edit if you want something that will make it super simple to put the components into an array

Comment: Your first solution seems ti be ok! Thanks!